# What is おやすみNASA胃？

Tags: meaning, puns

I've seen this in several places. Is that a set phrase? What does that mean?

I know that it's a way of saying "Goodnight," but the NASA胃 doesn't make sense.

Comment: Frankly, do you really expect it to make more sense to us with *less* context than you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

胃 is read い and NASA reads "なさ" so what this actually says is おやすみなさい ("Good night"). However, I don't know wether this is a typo or an intentional misspelling.

Comment: I think this is a pun.

Comment: It's probably an intentional phonetecism.  In Osaka-ben, it's common to use や in place of だ.  So 「だけど」 often becomes 「やけど」.  So sometimes I write 火傷　【やけど】 in the middle of a sentence to show this.  Same with 輩　【やから】 for だから.

Comment: It is obviously a pun (or an incredibly inept non-native typist), and a rather lazy one at that (unless the context really made an association with NASA or stomach matters meaningful). As @Istrasci points out, it is quite common in some circles (let's say urban kansai teenagers) to make up random ateji for common words. I have rarely seen romaji mixed-in but it reeks of a certain lack of imagination (for something that is not incredibly imaginative in the first place).

Comment: Maybe some kind of gyarumoji?

Comment: The final shuttle flight before the fleet was retired was around this time. There was some sense that America was no longer the pioneer in space. So, so long NASA.

Comment: Having spent some time now using Japanese Phones and Japanese Input on computers, I think that this could be a simple typo caused by the intricacies of Japanese input. I think Dave's explanation is the most likely, but I will add my idea for completeness: 

Assuming a user has repeatedly corrected the input 「なさ」 to 「NASA」, the user's computer will usually remember that choice. Inputing the phrase as 「おやすみ」「なさ」「い」 and using automatic conversion to Kanji for each of the parts in 「」 separately could then possibly cause this weird construction.

Some context would, however, be very helpful.